# Abelian-by-cyclic subgroups of exponential growth solvable groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, solvable-groups

I am currently looking for a reference to a proof (or counterexample) to the following statement:

**Statement:** Assume $G$ is a finitely generated solvable group of exponential growth, then there is a finitely generated subgroup $H$ of exponential growth which is either polycyclic or (virtually-)abelian-by-cyclic (i.e. it admits a short exact sequence $1 \to V \to H \to \mathbb{Z} \to 1$ where $V$ is virtually abelian).

It seems this result should be known (or known to false, or known to be open), since I could already sketch a strategy to produce the subgroup. Please understand that I'm interested in a reference (and I'm not asking anyone to check if the following strategy is sound). I wrote the strategy below just in case it helps ring a bell.

*Strategy:* First look at the largest integer $k$ so that $G^{(k)}$ (the $k^\text{th}$ derived group) contains a finitely generated subgroup which has exponential growth. Let $K$ be such a subgroup, then $[K,K]$ is locally virtually nilpotent.
  Case 1: if Si $[K,K]$ is finitely generated, then this is a polycyclic group.
  Case 2: Else, $Q = K/[K,K]$ is finitely generated abelian. Let $F_n$ be an increasing sequence of subgroups of $[K,K]$ such that $\cup F_n = [K,K]$. 
The elements $z \in K$ have an action on $[K,K]$ by conjugation. Look at the orbits of elements of $[K,K]$ under this action. Since $K$ is finitely generated and by the maximality of $k$, there is an element of $z \in K$ so that this action must have an unbounded orbit (not contained in some $F_n$) and it's quotient in $Q$ is non-trivial. Since the FC-centre of $[K,K]$ is a caracteristic subgroup and is not contained in some $F_n$, there is even an orbit $\mathcal{O}$ (of the conjugation action of $z$) which is unbounded in $F_C([K,K])$.

The desired subgroup $H$ is given by $1 \to U \to H \to Z \to 1$ where $Z$ is the subgroup generated by $z$ and $U$ is the subgroup generated by the orbit $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: By a 1984 result of Kropholler, every f.g. solvable group either has a lamplighter $C_p\wr\mathbf{Z}$ subquotient for some prime $p$, or is minimax. Hence, this reduces to proving the result assuming either $G$ minimax (which is quite close to polycyclic in spirit) or $G$ has a such a lamplighter as quotient (or if there is a counterexample, it could be found with either of these properties).

Comment: how interesting! is there a relatively recent book on the theory of (infinite) soluble groups? the most recent I could put my hands on was Robinson's "Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups".

Comment: apologies for this [well-known] question: what's an easy example of a solvable minimax groups which is not polycyclic?

Comment: An example is the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,k)$ for $k\ge 2$.

Comment: so if I replace "subgroup" by "subquotient" in the statement, then it is almost a corollary of Kropholler's result. (I still don't have a good grasp on minimax groups, but I guess it should be simpler to find a polycyclic or abelian-by-cyclic group in their minimax serie)

Comment: Yes sure the minimax (fg solvable) group are much easier to understand than general f.g. solvable ones; in particular they're virtually nilpotent-by-abelian.

Comment: About $BS(1,k)  = \langle a,b, \mid b^{-1}ab = a^k \rangle$ not being polycyclic: I'm confused. The definition of polycyclic I read is that there is a subnormal serie (of finite length) with cyclic quotients. Here $1 \lhd \langle a \rangle \lhd G$ is such a series. So I'm not using the proper definition of polycyclic? (see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Polycyclic_group) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycyclic_group) ) or I made another silly mistake... or perhaps these definitions are only suited for finite groups?

Comment: No, $\langle a\rangle$ is not a normal subgroup in $BS(1,k)=\langle a,b\mid b^{-1}ab=a^k\rangle$ for $k\ge 2$. Indeed $bab^{-1}\notin\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: obviously, thanks. So $G = BS(1,k) \simeq \mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{k}] \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ (where the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ is by multiplication by $k$) is minimax because $\mathbb{Z}$ is Max and $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{k}]$ is Min?  $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{k}]$ cannot be Max (not finitely generated), but I don't see why it's Min (the sequence $\langle k \rangle \geq \langle k^2 \rangle \geq \langle k^3 \rangle \ldots$ does not stabilise). So one needs to split $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{k}]$ agin?
$G$ cannot be polycyclic since $G^{(1)} / G^{(2)} = \mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{1}{k}]$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: $Z[1/k]$ is not min but $Z[1/k]/Z$ is min.